# What exactly is causing an error in this PHP code?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm not familiar with PHP and a friend of mine got this error message from their site:

> Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in
>   /var/www/wp-content/themes/framework/php/class-htmlhelper.php:222

[image]

Any help on what is needed would be greatly appreciated! I've tried to understand what component needs to become a string but I'm not sure...

Comment: Post code, not images.

Comment: Try to clearly reflect your problem in the title. If you give a general title, it'll be hard for other people to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In line number 218 you have to write $this->element to call a function.

Answer (score 1):

I think $this->$element['type'] not string.
You try print $this->$element['type']